# Как передать информацию из json в telegram bot?

Tags: python, json, telegram-bot, aiogram

Есть данные в json:

```
{
    "news": [
        {
            "author_name": "Natalia Mitina",
            "image_post": "https://st.hzcdn.com/fimgs/1b71806304f97611_6272-w458-h268-b0-p0--.jpg",
            "dir_post": "Практикующий дизайнер описывает методику поиска автора вашего будущего проекта",
            "title_post": "Пошаговое руководство: Как выбрать своего дизайнера интерьера",
            "comment_post": "25",
            "link_post": "https://www.houzz.ru/statyi/poshagovoe-rukovodstvo-kak-vybraty-svoego-dizaynera-interyera-stsetivw-vs~46791009"
        },
        {
            "author_name": "Ольга Божко",
            "image_post": "https://st.hzcdn.com/fimgs/pictures/living-rooms/courthouse-conversion-sigmar-img~a7f180140698f4b6_8348-1-383ec72-w458-h268-b0-p0.jpg",
            "dir_post": "Перед тем как завести ковер или расположить уже имеющийся — повторим несколько правил",
            "title_post": "Вопрос: Как определить, какого размера ковер вам нужен",
            "comment_post": "11",
            "link_post": "https://www.houzz.ru/statyi/horoshiy-vopros-kak-opredelity-kover-kakogo-razmera-vam-trebuetsya-stsetivw-vs~55517300"
        }
    ]
}
```

как передать эти данные в телеграмм бот в виде статей?

нашел такой вариант кода:

```
news = f"{hlink(v['article_title'], v['article_url'])}"
```

и он работает, когда структура json в таком виде:

```
{
    "521158": {

        "author_name": "Natalia Mitina",
        "image_post": "https://st.hzcdn.com/fimgs/1b71806304f97611_6272-w458-h268-b0-p0--.jpg",
        "dir_post": "Практикующий дизайнер описывает методику поиска автора вашего будущего проекта",
        "title_post": "Пошаговое руководство: Как выбрать своего дизайнера интерьера",
        "comment_post": "25",
        "link_post": "https://www.houzz.ru/statyi/poshagovoe-rukovodstvo-kak-vybraty-svoego-dizaynera-interyera-stsetivw-vs~46791009"
    },
    "521159": {
        "author_name": "Ольга Божко",
        "image_post": "https://st.hzcdn.com/fimgs/pictures/living-rooms/courthouse-conversion-sigmar-img~a7f180140698f4b6_8348-1-383ec72-w458-h268-b0-p0.jpg",
        "dir_post": "Перед тем как завести ковер или расположить уже имеющийся — повторим несколько правил",
        "title_post": "Вопрос: Как определить, какого размера ковер вам нужен",
        "comment_post": "11",
        "link_post": "https://www.houzz.ru/statyi/horoshiy-vopros-kak-opredelity-kover-kakogo-razmera-vam-trebuetsya-stsetivw-vs~55517300"
    }
}
```

Мой код:

```
import datetime
import json
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.utils.markdown import hbold, hunderline, hcode, hlink

bot = Bot("1111111111111111")
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler(commands="all_news")
async def get_all_news(message: types.Message):
    with open("news_dict.json") as file:
        news_dict = json.load(file)

    for k, v in sorted(news_dict.items()):
        news = f"{hlink(v['title_post'], v['link_post'])}"

        await message.answer(news)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

и не работает, если структура json как в моем варианте.
Хелпми плиз!
подскажите что делать в моем случае?

Comment: А где Ваш код? Здесь с экстрасенсами напряг.

Comment: @Namerek Добавил!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Вот так попробуйте

`pip install jmespath`
*Ну люблю я эту либу ничего с собой не могу поделать*

```
import datetime
import json
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.utils.markdown import hbold, hunderline, hcode, hlink

import jmespath as jp

bot = Bot("1111111111111111")
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler(commands="all_news")
async def get_all_news(message: types.Message):
    with open("news_dict.json") as file:
        news_dict = json.load(file)

    for k, v in jp.search(
            '*.[title_post,link_post]',
            news_dict

    ):
        news = f"{hlink(k, v)}"

        await message.answer(news)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

#### UPD к коментарию

```
for title, dir_p, author, link in jp.search(
            '*.[title_post,dir_post,author_name,link_post]',
            news_dict

    ):
    ...
```

Comment: По аналогии, добавляю в код дополнительные параметры 

 for k, v in jp.search(
            '*.[title_post,dir_post,author_name,link_post]',
            news_dict

и код перестает работать

Ошибка:
line 26, in get_all_news
    for k, v in jp.search(
        ^^^^

И что можно сделать с отображением строк в telegram? 

<a href="https://www.houzz.ru/statyi/skromnye-metry-12-mest-dlya-hraneniya-kotorye-vy-zrya-ignorirovali-stsetivw-vs~63672192">Скромные метры: 12 мест для хранения, которые вы зря игнорировали</a>

Comment: @Илья, конечно перестает. У Вас значений `title_post,dir_post,author_name,link_post` 4 а переменных в которые Вы это пытаетесь распаковать `k, v` две

Comment: `И что можно сделать с отображением строк в telegram?` Создавайте это другим вопросом и с подробностями

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Теперь разобрался.

Comment: @Илья, добавил в ответ подробности к Вашему комментарию

Comment: @Илья, Если часто парсите json'ы советую поподробней изучить `jmespath` и `pydantic`

Comment: Я так и сделаю!

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148218/discussion-between--and-namerek).

Comment: в бот попадает только 5 первых статей в json их 50!